# how to use patch and diff to merge two files and automatically resolve conflicts

Tags: text-processing, diff, xml, patch, merge

I have read about diff and patch but I can't figure out how to apply what I need.
I guess its pretty simple, so to show my problem take these two files:

a.xml

```
<resources>
   <color name="same_in_b">#AAABBB</color>
   <color name="not_in_b">#AAAAAA</color>
   <color name="in_b_but_different_val">#AAAAAA</color>
   <color name="not_in_b_too">#AAAAAA</color>
</resources>
```

b.xml

```
<resources>
   <color name="same_in_b">#AAABBB</color>
   <color name="in_b_but_different_val">#BBBBBB</color>
   <color name="not_in_a">#AAAAAA</color>
</resources>
```

I want to have an output, which looks like this (order doesn't matter):

```
<resources>
   <color name="same_in_b">#AAABBB</color>
   <color name="not_in_b">#AAAAAA</color>
   <color name="in_b_but_different_val">#BBBBBB</color>
   <color name="not_in_b_too">#AAAAAA</color>
   <color name="not_in_a">#AAAAAA</color>
</resources>
```

The merge should contain all lines along this simple rules:

1. any line which is only in one of the files
2. if a line has the same name tag but a different value, take the value from the second

I want to apply this task inside a bash script, so it must not nessesarily need to get done with diff and patch, if another programm is a better fit

Comment: `diff` can tell you which lines are in one file but not the other, but only on the granularity of entire lines. `patch` is only suitable for making the same changes to a similar file (perhaps a different version of the same file, or an entirely different file where however the line numbers and surrounding lines for each change are identical to your original file). So no, they are not particularly suitable for this task. You might want to have a look at `wdiff` but the solution probably requires a custom script. Since your data looks like XML, you might want to look for some XSL tool.

Comment: Why all the answers with custom scripts? Merging is a standard and complex problem, and there are good tools for it. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need `patch` for this; it's for extracting changes and sending them on without the unchanged part of the file.

The tool for merging two versions of a file is `merge`, but as `@vonbrand` wrote, you need the "base" file from which your two versions diverged. To do a merge without it, use `diff` like this:

```
diff -DVERSION1 file1.xml file2.xml > merged.xml
```

It will enclose each set of changes in C-style `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` "preprocessor" commands, like this:

```
#ifdef VERSION1
<stuff added to file1.xml>
#endif
...
#ifndef VERSION1
<stuff added to file2.xml>
#endif
```

If a line or region differs between the two files, you'll get a "conflict", which looks like this:

```
#ifndef VERSION1
<version 1>
#else /* VERSION1 */
<version 2>
#endif /* VERSION1 */
```

So save the output in a file, and open it in an editor. Search for any places where `#else` comes up, and resolve them manually. Then save the file and run it through `grep -v` to get rid of the remaining `#if(n)def` and `#endif` lines:

```
grep -v '^#if' merged.xml | grep -v '^#endif' > clean.xml
```

In the future, save the original version of the file. `merge` can give you much better results with the help of the extra information. (But be careful: `merge` edits one of the files in-place, unless you use `-p`. Read the manual).

Comment: I added something for if I had a conflict `sed -e "s/^#else.*$/\/\/ conflict/g"`

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. As I wrote in my answer, you should be removing the `#else` lines manually, in the editor during conflict resolution.

Answer (score 8):

`sdiff` (1) - side-by-side merge of file differences

Use the `--output` option, this will interactively merge any two files. You use simple [commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Merge-Commands.html#Merge-Commands) to select a change or edit a change.

You should make sure that the `EDITOR` environment variable is set. The default editor for commands like "eb" is usually [`ed`, a line editor](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/actually-using-ed/).

```
EDITOR=nano sdiff -o merged.txt file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: I find using `vim` as the EDITOR as better. But this is the best solution, it comes with the `diff` command too!

Answer (score 6):

`merge(1)` is probably nearer to what you want, but that requires a common ancestor to your two files.

A (dirty!) way of doing it is:

1. Get rid of the first and last lines, use `grep(1)` to exclude them
2. Smash the results together
3. `sort -u` leaves a sorted list, eliminates duplicates
4. Replace first/last line

Humm... something along the lines:

`echo '<resources>'; grep -v resources file1 file2 | sort -u; echo '</resources>'`

might do.

Comment: does work in this particular example, but NOT in general: If the `name` `in_b_but_different_val` has a value of `#00AABB` sort will put that on top and erases the second value instead of the first one

Comment: for the optimal solution in this case you'd have to parse the XML, with a real XML parser not the hacks above, and produce a new merged XML output from that. diff / patch / sort etc. are just all hacks tailored to "particular examples", for a general solution they're simply the wrong tools

Comment: @alzheimer, whip up something simple to show us...

Comment: Apparently `diff3` works the same way. Requiring a common ancestor file. Why is there no simple CLI tool that just merges 2 files together based on what `diff` shows.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple solution that works **merging up to 10 files**:

```
#!/bin/bash

strip(){
    i=0
    for f; do
        sed -r '
            /<\/?resources>/ d
            s/>/>'$((i++))'/
        ' "$f"
    done
}

strip "$@" | sort -u -k1,1 -t'>' | sed '
    1 s|^|<resources>\n|
    s/>[0-9]/>/
    $ a </resources>
'
```

**please note the arg that comes first has the precedence** so you have to call:

```
script b.xml a.xml
```

to get common values kept from `b.xml` rather than `a.xml`.

`script b.xml a.xml` outs:

```
<resources>
   <color name="in_b_but_different_val">#BBBBBB</color>
   <color name="not_in_a">#AAAAAA</color>
   <color name="not_in_b">#AAAAAA</color>
   <color name="not_in_b_too">#AAAAAA</color>
   <color name="same_in_b">#AAABBB</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another horrible hack - could be simplified, but :P

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

while read line
do
    if [ "${line:0:13}" == '<color name="' ]
    then
        a_keys[$i]="${line:13}"
        a_keys[$i]="${a_keys[$i]%%\"*}"
        a_values[$i]="$line"
        i=$((i+1))
    fi
done < a.xml

i=0

while read line
do
    if [ "${line:0:13}" == '<color name="' ]
    then
        b_keys[$i]="${line:13}"
        b_keys[$i]="${b_keys[$i]%%\"*}"
        b_values[$i]="$line"
        i=$((i+1))
    fi
done < b.xml

echo "<resources>"

i=0

for akey in "${a_keys[@]}"
do
    print=1

    for bkey in "${b_keys[@]}"
    do
        if [ "$akey" == "$bkey" ]
        then
            print=0
            break
        fi
    done

    if [ $print == 1 ]
    then
        echo "  ${a_values[$i]}"
    fi

    i=$(($i+1))
done

for value in "${b_values[@]}"
do
    echo "  $value"
done

echo "</resources>"
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, second try, now in Perl (*not* production quality, no checking!):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(A, "a.xml");

while(<A>) {
  next if(m;^\<resource\>$;);
  next if(m;^\<\/resource\>$;);
  ($name, $value) = m;^\s*\<color\s+name\s*\=\s*\"([^"]+)\"\>([^<]+)\<\/color\>$;;
  $nv{$name} = $value if $name;
}

close(A);

open(B, "b.xml");

while(<B>) {
  next if(m;^\<resource\>$;);
  next if(m;^\<\/resource\>$;);
  ($name, $value) = m;^\s*\<color\s+name\s*\=\*\"([^"]+)\"\>([^<]+)\<\/color\>$;;
  $nv{$name} = $value if $name;
}

close(B);

print "<resource>\n";
foreach (keys(%nv)) {
    print "   <color name=\"$_\">$nv{$_}</color>\n";
}
print "</resource>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one, using cut and grep... (takes a.xml b.xml as arguments)

```
#!/bin/bash

zap='"('"`grep '<color' "$2" | cut -d '"' -f 2 | tr '\n' '|'`"'")'
echo "<resources>"
grep '<color' "$1" | grep -E -v "$zap"
grep '<color' "$2"
echo "</resources>"
```

Comment: `echo` is the default action, so `xargs echo` is superfluous. Why don't you simply `tr '\n' '|'` anyway?

Comment: Good point - it's just a quick hack. I'll edit it.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use `join`:

```
JOIN(1)                            User Commands                            JOIN(1)

NAME
       join - join lines of two files on a common field

SYNOPSIS
       join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

DESCRIPTION
       For each pair of input lines with identical join fields, write a line to
       standard output. The default join field is the first, delimited by blanks.
```

i found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364455/merge-two-files-by-key-if-exists-in-the-first-file-bash-script

Comment: Could you explain *how* `join` would be used in this particular case?

Comment: So, "using `join`" may be a correct answer, but it's useless unless one knew how to apply `join` to this particular issue.  The `join` utility crucially does not read XML, for example.

Comment: The problem / requirements in the question you linked to  are significantly different from those in this question.